# Two norms $\|\cdot\|_a$ and $\|\cdot\|_b$ on $X$, and a function $f:X\to Y$ Fréchet differentiable with one of the norms but not with the other one?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

There is a theorem that

> if $f : (X,\|\cdot\|_{X1}) \to (Y,\|\cdot\|_{Y1}) $  is Fréchet differentiable, then replacing the norms with some equivalent norms $\|\cdot\|_{X2}$ and $\|\cdot\|_{Y2}$ preserves the differentiability.

I was trying to construct an example where a function is not Fréchet differentiable anymore after replacing the norms with norms that aren't equivalent.

The easiest example with not equivalent norms known to me is $\|x\|_\infty$ and $\|x\|_1$ on $C[0,1]$. Yet I can't think of any function, say, $f: C[0,1] \to \mathbb R$, that would be Fréchet differentiable with one of the norms but not with the other one.

Any help with finding such an example (not necessarily with the above mentioned norms) is highly appreciated.

Comment: Differentiable in what sense? Frechet?

Comment: @WillNelson: Yes, Frechet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one example that depends on your definition of Fréchet derivative.
Here I am taking the underlying space to be a normed space, not necessarily
Banach.

Note that if $\phi$ is linear and has a Fréchet derivative, then
$D \phi(x) = \phi$ (where $D\phi$ represents the Fréchet derivative of $\phi$). Hence if $\phi$ is linear, but not continuous, it does **not**
have a Fréchet derivative.

Let $Ef = f(0)$, be the evaluation operator.

Note that $E$ is linear & continuous
with respect to $\| \cdot \|_\infty$, hence $DE(f) = E$, where $DE$ represents
the Fréchet derivative of $E$.

However, $E$ is not continuous with respect to $\|\cdot \|_1$ (take
$f_n(x) = (1-x)^n$, then $\|f_n\|_1 \to 0$, but $Ef_n = 1$).

Hence $E$ is Fréchet differentiable with respect to $\| \cdot \|_\infty$
but not $\|\cdot \|_1$.